# QT 5.1 Adding polygons to the scene through the constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I'm doing a university assignment. I'm using the QT version 5.1. I made a class of transition names and its constructor, I need in that constructor to draw all polygons and invite that constructor to the dialog.cpp and to show on the scene everything from that constructor, but he only shows the last polygon number six. If someone has a solution, I'd like you to help me. Thank you.

```
tranzicija::tranzicija()
{
    //Crtanje poligona start => ready
    pol1  << QPoint( 135,135 );
    pol1 << QPoint( 190,190 );
    setPolygon(pol1);
    setPen(QPen(Qt::green,7));
    //scene()->addItem(newPoly1);

    //Crtanje poligona wait => ready
    pol2  << QPoint( 280,280 );
    pol2  << QPoint( 340,340 );
    setPolygon(pol2);
    setPen(QPen(Qt::green,7));
    //scene->addItem(newPoly2);

    //Crtanje poligona run => wait
    pol3  << QPoint( 415,341 );
    pol3  << QPoint( 480,276 );
    setPolygon(pol3);
    setPen(QPen(Qt::green,7));
    //scene->addItem(newPoly3);

    //Crtanje poligona run => stop
    pol4  << QPoint( 545,205 );
    pol4  << QPoint( 600,150 );
    setPolygon(pol4);
    setPen(QPen(Qt::green,7));
    //scene->addItem(newPoly4);

    //Crtanje poligona ready => run
    pol5  << QPoint( 300,250 );
    pol5  << QPoint( 430,250 );
    setPolygon(pol5);
    setPen(QPen(Qt::green,7));
    //scene->addItem(newPoly5);

    //Crtanje poligona run => ready
    pol6  << QPoint( 310,215 );
    pol6  << QPoint( 435,215 );
    setPolygon(pol6);
    setPen(QPen(Qt::green,7));
    //scene->addItem(newPoly6);
}
    ////Dialog.cpp
    tranzicija *obj = new tranzicija();
    scene->addItem(obj);
```

Comment: I read this three times and I still have no clue what you are trying to achieve. Maybe seeing the definition of `tranzicia` class would help...

Comment: I'm guessing that `tranzicia` inherits from `QGraphicsPolygonItem`?  If so then you only ever create and add a single instance having called `setPolygon` and `setPen` multiple times on that instance in its constructor.

Comment: I'm trying to draw more polygons and add to the scene, if you understand me, the problem is that I'm only showing one polygon on stage and the last one, and the rest not. The polygon inherits QGraphicsPolygonItem.

Comment: @G.M. Can you give me one example for this if it's not a problem, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Help,help!!

Create a new class and call it transition that will create all the transitions in the shape of an arrow in the process state diagram in the picture. The transition class should inherit QObject and QGraphicsPolygonItem class.

Constructor of the transition class so that the length, rotation and coordinates on the stage (position) of the arrow can be passed. (2 points)
Within the transitions class designer, create an arrow-shaped polygon using the above-mentioned class structural paramaters. Paint the arrow using the QBrush instance class.

Comment: Is this an answer, additional information for your question, or a new question?